# Android Push Notification Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Android push notification from Firebase data is handled only when app is opened and if app is in background or not running the Firebase brings a notification with title and body from the notification tag on push. How can I handle the data tag when app is in background or not running. I have tried the following code:

```
public static String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

     Log.e(TAG,"Test_Data:"+remoteMessage.getData().toString());

    }
```

But it works only when the app is opened and I cant handle the data only the notification tag which is basically handled by Firebase itself!

Answer (score 2):

For handling data in the same way for foreground, background and killed states, you have to send a **Data message** instead of **Notification message**. Data messages are received in `onMessageReceived()` at all times. You can do this by including **only the data tag** inside the json.

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "data":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

If you include a notification object inside this json, then it is considered as a **Notification message** and the data part is delivered only when it is tapped